# Один - в Чувашии, и сразу два - в Нижегородской - Как объяснить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение: На всей Волге в 2014 году было построено 4 объекта берегоукрепления: один - в Ярославской области, один - в Чувашии, и сразу два - в Нижегородской области. Нужна ли запятая перед "и". Мне кажется, что не надо.

Comment: В неполных предложениях (для связки) ставится знак тире "——", но не "-". Вёрстка того требует и приветствует от лица читателей.

Comment: Вёрстка, моджет, требует, компьютерный текст на экране - нет. Спутать с дефисом невозможно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужна ли запятая перед "и".

М-да... По правилам-то вроде бы и не нужна, но с запятой предложение лучше читается. Я бы поставил.

Answer (score 3):

После двоеточия идут неполные предложения, поэтому запятая перед "и" вполне уместна